# Get User-Agent and IP Address of object anonymously uploaded to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ip-address, user-agent

Is there a way to retrieve the User-Agent and/or IP Address of the client that uploaded an object anonymously to an S3 bucket?

I'm using an anonymous upload method similar to this: https://gist.github.com/jareware/d7a817a08e9eae51a7ea

which shows a method of *testing* against the client's `User-Agent` (via. `aws:UserAgent` in a `StringNotEquals` block in the `Condition` block), and there is [documentation that shows that `aws:SourceIp` exists as well](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition), but I see no way of grabbing either after the file has been uploaded.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you enabled logging on the bucket...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

...or captured a bucket notification event about the upload...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

Otherwise, no.

Anonymous uploads are just a really, really bad idea.  You can end up with objects where the only available action to you is deleting them.  Bucket ownership != object ownership.  Authenticating requests is simply not that difficult, so I would encourage you to back away slowly from anonymous S3 writes.

Comment: Ahh excellent! I knew there had to be a way - thank you! Re anonymous uploads: I'm requiring files to be uploaded with the `bucket-owner-full-control` canned ACL, so I'm still in full control of them. Thank you for the warning, though :D